# Populate PS1 asynchronously

Tags: bash, prompt, bashrc, async

I have a few git svn related functions that see if I have to pull/push from/to the repository.

My problem is that the functions I've written to gather this information are too slow. I'd like to make them async so that `PS1` shows a default, if though the data produced by the functions is ready I want it printed.

I'd like to have these information in my prompt – so that, for example, I know if I have to pull – without doing a `git svn fetch` everytime.

This is the function I call to add a ↑ to my PS1 if I have to push my changes.

```
function hasToPush {
    (($1 == 0)) && 
        (git svn dcommit --dry-run 2>/dev/null | grep -q "diff-tree" && echo "↑")
}
```

These are the functions I call to add a ↓ if I have to pull. The first is used to refresh my index every 2 minutes so that I can do the `(($latest > $current))` check.

```
function loopingGitSvnFetch {
     sleep 120
     git svn fetch &>/dev/null
}
loopingGitSvnFetch &
function hasToPull {
    (($1 == 0)) && (
        latest=$(git svn log | awk 'NR==2' | cut -d ' ' -f1 | tr -d 'r')
        current=$2
        (($latest > $current)) && echo "↓"
    )
}
```

To make them async, I've tried to put them together like this:

```
function async {
    {
     git diff-index --quiet --cached HEAD &>/dev/null
     dirty=$(echo $?)
     push=$(hasToPush $dirty)
     gitsvn=$(git svn info 2> /dev/null | grep Revision)
     gitsvn=${gitsvn#Revision: }
     pull=$(hastoPull $dirty $gitsvn)
     callback $push $pull
     } &
 }
```

But that produces the same slow behaviour.
I've tried to put results in a file and then read it after, but I don't like that approach.

I've thought about using `PROMPT_COMMAND`. But that would not be async; it would be on demand.

Could you shed some light on how `PS1` behaves or on what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

PS: Could someone with 300 rep add the async and ps1 tags?

EDIT:

I added these line to my .bashrc as a simple test, it seemed to work, so having rewrote them (I reverted my previous attempt) seems was a good thing :)

```
while true;
do
    discoverScmInfo &>~/.ps1
    sleep 1
done &
PS1='$(customW)$(cat ~/.ps1)\$ '
```

I'll put this in a function and check if the job is already running before calling it.
Sorry about this, after all it seems that all I needed was to write about it. :)

Comment: Regarding tags: `async` might be useful, but one might usually have either `jobs` or `parallel` instead, so we'll see if it catches on. But defnitely not `PS1` - it is just a shell configuration variable; you have the **`prompt`** tag for what you mean.

Comment: Why don't you like the file-based approach? It really seems the only reasonable one to me. Maybe optimizing it would be enough for you - please show, how did you use this approach.

Comment: While I was coding I thought it would not be such a great idea to start creating dotfiles around my home. I reverted all my changes to bashrc, so now I've reimplemented it and it seems to work ok ^^". Sorry about this. Btw, since this is not a problem anymore, do you have some hints on making this better?

Answer (score 2):

re: your solution of a loop every second: you could write to a file in /tmp, instead of in your home directory.  And `PS1=$(customW)$(< ~/.ps1)\$ '` would save a fork/exec of `cat`.

re: the original question: how to get an async update to `PS1`:
To start an async write to `PS1`:

- set `PROMPT_COMMAND` to a function that checks if the data is available.
- - If it is, update `PS1` and unset `PROMPT_COMMAND`
- - If not, leave `PS1` with the old or placeholder value.

Use a file in `/tmp` for the async IO to write to, and `PROMPT_COMMAND` to read from.

I think this should work.