# Save cursor position and restore it in terminal

Tags: shell, terminal, prompt, async, terminfo

I am playing with some terminal capabilities to create async prompt output on `bash`. I want to get something like this: while outputting string in `PROMPT_COMMAND`, save terminal cursor position, print put `...` and go do other stuff (printing other info for example); then some time later *go back* to memorized position and print something new. `PS1` is designed that way that command itself is put on newline, so that async output is just text in terminal.

I found out `cup` terminfo entry to move cursor to given position, an there are escape codes to get current position (for examble, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575037/how-to-get-the-cursor-position-in-bash)). But for me, seems like all of them work with cursor position on screen, rather than in terminal buffer. That means that after putting new line my remembered position will be wrong.

Are there any way to work with terminal cursor position to store and restore cursor position based on buffer position? You can assume that the remembered position is still in visible part of the buffer (so you actually can put cursor there), but it might go up several lines up. For now, let's not consider race conditions. If no, I will try to find other tricks.

There is `zsh` shell which actually has async prompt support, but I don't actually know will it work if before output user will press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go to new line.

Comment: I saw [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25205/populate-ps1-asynchronously) approach to async prompt, but my prompt output is 3 lines long, so no `PS1`...

Answer (score 20):

Most of the terminals you are likely to use implement escape sequences for saving and restoring the cursor position.  Those are the `sc` (save cursor) and `rc` (restore cursor) capabilities in the terminal description, which you can use via `tput` (just like `cup`):

```
tput sc
tput cup 50 10
echo some stuff
echo more stuff
tput rc
```

However, if your program writes enough text to force scrolling, the restored position will still be on the same place on the terminal's screen.  It does not move along with the scrolled text.

POSIX, by the way, documents only *part* of `tput` because the tool is actually part of another standard, X/Open Curses.  That is summarized in the [portability](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html#h2-PORTABILITY) section of the manual page.

Back to the question: there are no escape sequences which track the *buffer* position (accounting for scrolling).  To get that, your application would have to keep track of what was sent to the screen.  Solving that sort of problem is what the curses library is for.  In a plain command-line application, there is not much that you can do.

Comment: Too bad, I need to record position, then scroll for sure, then go back. Thanks for effort

Comment: In nodeJS, https://github.com/sindresorhus/log-update library simulates that by actually counting emitted lines (accounting for line wrapping, discounting ansi color sequences), then using correct number of Erase Line sequences to go back and replace it. Could use similar code but move up instead of erasing.  However, no such approach can work with race condition wrt. to user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>,  unless managed by the shell/readline itself.

Comment: That's subject to the same limitation with respect to scrolling (would require the script to know where the cursor is, to use in that computation).